# PowerShell New-ADUser creating disabled user anyways

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

This is a piggyback on [Powershell New-ADUser error handling password complexity (ActiveDirectory module)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements) as it is regarding the scenario where the password complexity rules aren't satisfied when doing something like this and a new (disabled) user gets created anyways:

```
New-ADUser test1 -Givenname test -surname test -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "abc" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

I've attempted `try/catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException]` as well as `$ErrorAction = Stop` in tandem with using `New-ADUser... -ErrorAction Stop` as suggested in the linked post to prevent a new (disabled) user from being created if the password fails the complexity check to no avail.

The environment I'm using is Server 2019 and PS 5.1

I'm curious to determine why using `$ErrorAction = "Stop"` along with `New-ADUser... -ErrorAction Stop` evidently worked in the past to prevent the creation of a disabled user but doesn't today.  I've searched high and low and can't come up with a solution or more importantly an understanding of why using `ErrorAction` in any capacity isn't working the way I'm expecting it to in this specific circumstance.  Can anyone help un-idiot this part of my day?

-UPDATED QUESTION TEXT BELOW-

In order to apply this in a prod environment I'm motivated to follow the complexity rules as they are officially [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements), specifically:

**"Any Unicode character that's categorized as an alphabetic character but isn't uppercase or lowercase. This group includes Unicode characters from Asian languages."**

I ran across a [post](https://www.checkyourlogs.net/active-directory-password-complexity-check-powershell-mvphour/) that implements fairly solid regex patterns, but as a user commented at the bottom - the copyright symbol (among others - like pi π) is supposed to be valid, but the regex patterns offered don't account for a subset of unicode characters.  It seemed reasonable to pursue 1 of 2 solutions so that all accepted characters will be allowed:

1. Craft the perfect regex to account for all allowed unicode characters as described in the MS documentation
2. Use try/catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException] , as this *should* reliably reject passwords that don't meet the complexity rules in their entirety.

For password complexity rule-compliance in prod (and to avoid creating new disabled users if the password isn't accepted), it seemed that #2 would be a more sound method compared to manually accounting for all known exceptions.  Am I going about this from a poor angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TLDR;

Using the `[ADSI]` type accelerator in tandem with a try/catch block appears to be a working solution that will prevent account creation in the event of an exception being thrown (bad password, etc) when creating a new AD account.

In attempting to remain consistent with and mimic Active Directory account creation, I eventually discovered that if an AD account is created in AD (using the wizard) and the password fails complexity/policy requirements, the account is still created and an RID is burned from the pool in the process (2³⁰ -1 RIDs in the pool, so no big deal).

The account is deleted immediately after -- obviously only if the user doing the account creation has the appropriate rights to delete AD users.  If the user lacks those rights, the account deletion fails (and an another error message is presented following the 'bad password' error message) and the account is created without a password and is disabled.

I incorrectly assumed that the account was *not* being created when password requirements weren't met during the account creation process when using the native Win32 'Create Object - User' wizard in AD as well as the newer Active Directory Administrative Center that uses PowerShell.  In the latter case you can peek at the PowerShell History Viewer to see each step.  In both cases, the same procedure is followed: Create account, attempt to set password, delete account if password fails.

However, it's still possible to prevent account creation (when the submitted password fails complexity/policy requirements) by using the [ADSI] accelerator in PowerShell.  There's a module in the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) that achieves this goal.

The author ([lazywinadmin)](https://github.com/lazywinadmin) created a [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AdsiPS/1.0.0.9) that features several ADSI'ed alternatives to the ActiveDirectory module cmdlets.  The benefit to using ADSI is that it doesn't require RSAT or the ActiveDirectoy module to be installed.

I'm not going to post someone else's code in an answer, but their module contains a function `New-ADSIUser` that demonstrates how preventing account creation in the event of a thrown exception (bad password, etc) can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating disabled users because the password does not comply to the domains password complexity rules, you could use this helper function:

```
function Test-DomainPassword {
    # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Password,

        [string]$SamAccountName = $null,
        [string]$DisplayName = $null
    )
    $PasswordPolicy = Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($Password.Length -lt $PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength) {
        Write-Verbose "Password '$Password' is too short. Minimal length is $($PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength)"
        return $false
    }
    if (($SamAccountName) -and ($Password -match [regex]::Escape($SamAccountName))) {
        Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes the users SamAccountName"
        return $false
    }
    if ($DisplayName) {
        # The displayName is parsed for delimiters: commas, periods, dashes or hyphens, underscores, spaces, pound signs, and tabs.
        # If any of these delimiters are found, the displayName is split and all parsed sections (tokens) are confirmed not to be
        # included in the password.
        # Tokens that are shorter than three characters are ignored, and substrings of the tokens aren't checked.
        $tokens = $DisplayName.Split(",.-,_ #`t")
        foreach ($token in $tokens) {
            if (($token) -and ($token.Length -ge 3) -and ($Password -match [regex]::Escape($token))) {
                Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes (part of) the users DisplayName"
                return $false
            }
        }
    }
    if ($PasswordPolicy.ComplexityEnabled) {
        # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb726984(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
        # chapter 'Passwords Must Meet Complexity Requirements':
        # Passwords must use three of the four available character types:
        # lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, and symbols.

        $failures = @()
        # check for presence of
        # - Uppercase: A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Uppercase characters"
        }
        # - Lowercase: a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Lowercase characters"
        }
        # - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
        if ($Password -notmatch "[\d]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing digits (0-9)"
        }
        # - Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
        if ($Password -notmatch "[^\w]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;`"'<>,.?/"
        }
        # test if we have more than 1 mismatch (password needs at least 3 out of 4 to be OK)
        if ($failures.Count -gt 1) {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' failed because:`r`n{0}" -f ($failures -join "`r`n")
            return $false
        }
    }

    $true
}
```

Use it like this:

```
# both parameters -SamAccountName and -DisplayName are optional
if (Test-DomainPassword -Password 'abc' -SamAccountName 'test1' -DisplayName 'Paul Test' -Verbose) {
    # the password is OK, create the new user here:
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName        = 'test1'
        GivenName             = 'Paul'
        Surname               = 'Test'
        DisplayName           = 'Paul Test'
        AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'abc' -AsPlainText -force
        Enabled               = $true
        # etcetera
    }

    New-ADUser @userParams
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User 'test1' NOT created because the password did not pass the test"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Theo!  This is working to avoid creating a new user when the password doesn't meet the criteria in your script.  I tried testing your code with the password "1234aBπ" and it unfortunately rejected that password (I was able to manually create a new user in ADUC with that same password).  I've updated my original question with better details.

Comment: @Paul Please see my edited version. On [this old microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb726984(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) I found that a password must meet at least 3 out of the 4 complexity rules. The function now respects that where it formerly returned $false if any of the 4 rules were not met. That is why password `1234aBπ` failed the test before.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements

This is the current documentation link I am referring to, which includes unicode.  I am not rock solid on the spectrum of try/catch's that don't work as expected.  I don't have dissatisfaction with the solution you've offered, but for my own learning I'm curious to know at this point why catching the specific exception `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPasswordComplexityException]` doesn't work.  Do you have any insight as to why that isn't working?

Comment: @Paul Well, it seems that if other parameters are good enough, the user _is_ created. Only then the password is set but can fail on the complexity rules which aren't checked beforehand. If that fails, the newly  created user is disabled, not removed and the ADPasswordComplexityException is never thrown when using the New-ADUser cmdlet..